# При уменьшении экрана опускается блок

Tags: html, css

При уменьшении экрана сползает блок ( с текстом, на полупрозрачном фоне) с картинки.

Ширина ставится под размер картинки нормально, но при уменьшении всё ниже и ниже от своего нужного положения.

Как можно текстовый блок четко привязать к своей позиции, дабы он не уезжал куда не следует?

```css
.prop_el {
  width: 47%;
  margin: 12px 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.prop_el_cont {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 356px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.prop_el_cont a {
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.prop_el_cont a .picture {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

.prop_s1 {
  background: url('http://cdn.goodshomedesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Kvale-Hytte-Cottage-1.jpg') center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 120% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.prop_txt {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 298px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  vertical-align: middle;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.prop_txt_area {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 9px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.prop_txt_left {
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  width: 67%;
}

.prop_txt_right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: -19px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.prop_txt_det {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin-top: 39px;
}

.prop_txt_price {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.prop_el_cont:hover .prop_txt {
  top: 218px;
}
```

```html
<div class="prop_el">
  <div class="prop_el_cont">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="picture">
        <div class="prop_s1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="prop_txt">
        <span class="prop_txt_area">
        <span class="prop_txt_left">205 West 19th Street, 9th Floor</span>
        <span class="prop_txt_right">Chelsea</span>
        </span>
        <span class="prop_txt_det">кровати: 4, дивана: 4</span>
        <span class="prop_txt_price">9,850,000</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

p.s. `postition: absolute` для блока с текстом пробовал, все равно сползает, также пробовал вместо `top` использовать `bottom`.

[image: Выглядеть должно именно так, текстовый блок с описанием всегда должен быть прижат к назначенному месту (к низу картинки).]

Ссылка на код - https://jsfiddle.net/y0km562h/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый вариант просто поставить фиксированную высоту для блока с картинкой:

```
.prop_s1 {
    height: 458px;
}
```

Второй вариант исправить то, как вы сейчас используете свойство `background-size`:

```
.prop_s1 {
    background-size: cover;
}// в этом случае у вас будет немного обрезаться изображение
```

Третий вариант:

```
.prop_txt {
   font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 display: block;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 20px;
 text-align: left;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -79px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 999;
}
.prop_el_cont a .picture {
    display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 0;
}
.prop_el_cont {
 width: 100%;
 height: 255px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
.prop_el {
 width: 47%;
 margin: 12px 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url('http://cdn.goodshomedesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Kvale-Hytte-Cottage-1.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.block__body {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  bottom: -100px;
}
.block:hover .block__body {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x small-up-2 align-center">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="block__body">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```